# awk: look at next few lines without changing NR

Tags: awk

I have a input like this:

```
touchDown(9, 296, 413);
usleep(49699.75);
touchUp(9, 295, 413);
usleep(880305.71);

touchDown(9, 282, 397);
touchDown(10, 310, 536);
usleep(66298.79);
touchUp(9, 283, 402);
touchUp(10, 312, 538);
usleep(1300114.83);

touchDown(2, 313, 634);
touchDown(3, 257, 341);
touchDown(11, 349, 474);
touchMove(3, 69, 637);
usleep(16339.04);
touchMove(3, 34, 477);
usleep(49276.96);
touchUp(2, 311, 633);
touchUp(3, 253, 341);
touchUp(11, 344, 475);
```

Now I want eg. to take a look if a block (which always starts with /touchDown/) has /touchMove/ somewhere in it. If so, don´t print the block or edit it somehow. But awk goes through line by line and there seems no way to get a few lines back, once these lines where processed.

I thought the getline function would help me, but it seems as it also increases NR. Some Solutions I found here, where to put the previous line in a variable, which might be ok for just one line, but if such a block goes through many lines it seems very inconvinient.

This "you cant go back" of awk just messes me up...

Do you have any solution for this? Or is another language just better for things like this?

Thank you

Comment: What defines a "block"? The blank lines? What do you need to *do* with these "blocks" once you've identified/found them?

Comment: Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins as you are missing some awk fundamentals including the most important one - awk is record oriented, not line oriented, it just splits records on newlines by default. If you are ever considering using `getline` then make sure you first read and fully understand everything document at http://awk.info/?tip/getline and then you usually will not use it. There is no better language for text manipulation, you just need to learn how it works rather than trying to force it to act the way you think it should.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, very true. I usualy google together my knowledge, I should be more systematic and things would be easier for me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having that *a record* is defined by a an empty line, and a field is delimited by a single newline, you can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^touchMove/){print;next}}}' FS='\n' RS='\n\n'
```

The command is checking every field if it starts with *touchMove* and prints the whole *record* in that case.

This can be also simplified to:

```
awk '/\ntouchMove/' FS='\n' RS='\n\n'
```

which means *print the record if it contains the term 'touchMove' after a newline*

---

Following [EtanReisner's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902825/awk-look-at-next-few-lines-without-changing-nr/33902971?noredirect=1#comment55568720_33902971) we can simplify even the above command to:

```
awk '/\ntouchMove/' RS=''
```

since:

*EtanReisner*

> RS='' sets awk into "paragraph mode" which delimits input with blank lines too. It also automatically uses newlines for FS (in addition to whatever single character that FS is set to). So FS='\n' RS='\n\n' could be replaced with just RS=''

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html

Thanks for that!

Comment: `RS=''` sets awk into "paragraph mode" which delimits input with blank lines too. It also automatically uses newlines for `FS` (in addition to whatever single character that `FS` is set to). So `FS='\n' RS='\n\n'` could be replaced with just `RS=''`.

Comment: @EtanReisner Really?? Nice! :)

Comment: Yup. See [Multiple-Line Records](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html) for example.

Comment: Hm, I think this should work. I dont have to draw any connections between the paragraphs and if I´ll study awk´s string functions to tear apart the lines (now FSs ) I could manage to get my project done.  Thanks both of you for your Help. :)

Comment: I think the discussion about `FS` when `RS` is null is misleading. Setting `RS` has zero effect on `FS`. The default value of `FS` is `" "` which tells awk to separate each record into fields separated by `every chain of consecutive white space chars`. A newline is just one more white space char. Setting RS to null or many other non-newline values doesn't change `FS`, it just means newlines might now be present in a record and so when awk is splitting on the default FS, the white space characters FS is looking for can include newlines. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for pointing that out! I'm wondering why `'/\ntouchMove/'` works. I mean the `\n`. I did not expected that.

Comment: Still wondering.. I've, for whatever reason, tried `awk '$2~/,1/' FS=',' <<< '2,1,3'` what should have the same effect but it is of course not working. Why is `/\ntouchMove/` working then?

Comment: The script in your comment is splitting the record on `,` and then trying to test if a `,` is present in a field which it cannot be since all of the `,`s are BETWEEN fields not part of any one field. Your script above is testing for `\n` being present in a RECORD, not in a FIELD. If you modify the script in your comment to `awk '/,1/' FS=',' <<< '2,1,3'` THEN the 2 scripts will be functionally equivalent.

Comment: Oh yes!! I don't understand my own code anymore!! :) . Tired for today... Thanks!